# Getting wrong answer for below query

Tags: sql, oracle

Given the CITY and COUNTRY tables, query the names of all the continents (COUNTRY.Continent) and their respective average city populations (CITY.Population) rounded down to the nearest integer.

Note: CITY.CountryCode and COUNTRY.Code are matching key columns.

COUNTRY SCHEMA

[image: COUNTRY SCHEMA]

CITY SCHEMA

[image: CITY SCHEMA]

Accepted one

```
select COUNTRY.CONTINENT, FLOOR(AVG(CITY.POPULATION)) 
FROM COUNTRY , CITY WHERE COUNTRY.CODE = CITY.COUNTRYCODE GROUP BY COUNTRY.CONTINENT;
```

As we know that in country table population of each country given and we can use
the country table itself here so why i am getting wrong answer for this ?

```
SELECT C1.CONTINENT , FLOOR(AVG(C1.POPULATION))
FROM COUNTRY C1,COUNTRY C2    WHERE C1.CODE=C2.CODE GROUP BY C1.CONTINENT;
```

Comment: Kindly show your error/wrong output and expected output. Also, its not a good idea to represent table schema in image. Please edit the question and make necessary changes so that other users can help you.

Comment: Why the country self join? With a unique contry code, `FROM COUNTRY C1,COUNTRY C2    WHERE C1.CODE=C2.CODE` joins every row to itself, which makes no sense.

Answer (score 3):

In the first query, you are computing the average *city* population for each continent.

The second query is different, in the sense that it computes the average *country* population for each continent (nb: there is no need to JOIN to get that result, a simple aggregate query on COUNTRY is sufficient).

Remarks regarding your (first) query: always use explicit JOINs syntax instead of implicit, old-school JOINs. Using table aliases is also a good habit: they make the query more readable

Consider:

```
SELECT 
    co.CONTINENT,
    FLOOR(AVG(ci.POPULATION)) 
FROM COUNTRY co
INNER JOIN CITY ci ON co.CODE = ci.COUNTRYCODE 
GROUP BY co.CONTINENT
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
SELECT COUNTRY.Continent, FLOOR(AVG(CITY.Population))
from COUNTRY inner join CITY on city.countrycode = country.code
GROUP BY COUNTRY.CONTINENT
```

Comment: "You can try this"? Why should they? Please don't write code-only answers. Instead, describe what your query does differently from the OP's queries and how that solves the issues.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).